# i want to add two Version to config.SwaggerDoc in services.AddSwaggerGen for implemet swagger

Tags: swagger

I want to add two Versions to the config.SwaggerDoc in services.AddSwaggerGen to implement Swagger

for example:

```
services.AddSwaggerGen(
            config =>
            {
              
                config.SwaggerDoc("v1.1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "BookingApis V1", Version = "v1.1", Description = "Developed By Demon" });
                config.SwaggerDoc("v2", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "BookingApis V2", Version = "v2", Description = "Developed By Demon" });
```

}
);

these settings are necessary for me to implement swagger in Asp.Net and .core6
these settings adds in startup in the section of services.AddSwaggerGen

Answer (score 0):

I found this issue your answer is:

```
app.UseSwaggerUI(options =>
        { 
            options.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "Booking API V1");
            options.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v2/swagger.json", "Booking  API V2");

            {
                foreach (var description in provider.ApiVersionDescriptions)
                {
                    options.SwaggerEndpoint(
                        $"/swagger/{description.GroupName}/swagger.json",
                        description.GroupName);
                }
            }
        });
```